# How to authenticate with Facebook Id using AWS Cognito?

Tags: facebook, amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I want to authenticate user with Facebook Login using AWS Cognito Unity SDK.

This is my code:

```
void Start()

{
    InitCognito ();

}
public void InitCognito()
{
    UnityInitializer.AttachToGameObject (this.gameObject);
    credentials = new CognitoAWSCredentials (
        identity_pool_id, // Identity Pool ID
        region // Region
    );

    Debug.Log ("identity_pool_id = " + identity_pool_id + " region = " + region);

    credentials.GetIdentityIdAsync(delegate(AmazonCognitoIdentityResult<string>
        result) {
        if (result.Exception != null) {
            Debug.LogError(result.Exception.ToString());
        }
        string identityId = result.Response;
        Debug.Log("identityId = "+identityId);
        FBInit();
    });



}



public void FBInit()
{
    FB.Init(this.OnInitComplete, this.OnHideUnity);
    Debug.Log( "FB.Init() called with " + FB.AppId);

}

public void FBLogin()
{

    FB.LogInWithReadPermissions(new List<string>() { "public_profile", "email", "user_friends" }, this.HandleResult);

}


private void OnInitComplete()
{
    Debug.Log( "Success - Check log for details");
    Debug.Log("Success Response: OnInitComplete Called\n");
    Debug.Log( string.Format(
        "OnInitCompleteCalled IsLoggedIn='{0}' IsInitialized='{1}'",
        FB.IsLoggedIn,
        FB.IsInitialized));

    if (AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken != null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Access token = "+AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken.ToString());
    }
    FBLogin ();
}

private void OnHideUnity(bool isGameShown)
{
    Debug.Log( "Success - Check log for details");
    Debug.Log(string.Format("Success Response: OnHideUnity Called {0}\n", isGameShown));
    Debug.Log("Is game shown: " + isGameShown);
}
protected void HandleResult(IResult result)
{
    if (result == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Null Response\n");

        return;
    }



    // Some platforms return the empty string instead of null.
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Error))
    {
        Debug.Log( "Error - Check log for details");
        Debug.Log( "Error Response:\n" + result.Error);
    }
    else if (result.Cancelled)
    {
        Debug.Log ("Cancelled - Check log for details");
        Debug.Log( "Cancelled Response:\n" + result.RawResult);
    }
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.RawResult))
    {
        Debug.Log ("Success - Check log for details");
        Debug.Log ("Success Response:\n" + result.RawResult);
        Debug.Log ("Access Token = "+AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken);
        Debug.Log ("Access Token = "+AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken.TokenString);
        Debug.Log ("Access User Id =" + AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken.UserId);
        credentials.AddLogin ("graph.facebook.com", AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken.TokenString);
        if (credentials.CurrentLoginProviders.Length > 0) {
            Debug.Log (credentials.CurrentLoginProviders[0]);
        }

        Debug.Log (credentials.GetCachedIdentityId());
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log ( "Empty Response\n");
    }


}
```

When the `InitCognito()` method is executed, I get a unAuthorized Identity Id(once I reinstall this app on the same device, the unAuthorized Identity Id changes). Then I can get the Facebook user id and token successfully.

Following the Cognito Developer Guide, I use `credentials.AddLogin()` to add Facebook login. But after this method executed, Debug.Log `(credentials.GetCachedIdentityId())` shows that the Identity Id is the same as the unAuthorized Identity Id, not a specific id referenced to the Facebook Id and the AWS Cognito console shows that there is no "Linked Login".  Do I use `credentials.AddLogin()` in a wrong way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Setting the login token doesn't necessarily mean that the SDK is sending it to the server. Can you try running the below command, which should force it? I'm guessing the reason you're seeing the same identity is that it hasn't updated the server to the change. It's pulled from the Cognito [developer guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-credentials.html).

```
credentials.GetIdentityIdAsync(delegate(AmazonCognitoIdentityResult<string> result) {
    if (result.Exception != null) {
        //Exception!
    }
    string identityId = result.Response;
});
```